# Calling other decision Decision table which is part of other flow in Drools

Tags: drools, jbpm

I have created Two flow with multiple Rules and Decision Tables.

While calling startProcess method, it will call decision table which is not a part of provided flow.

for example,

While executing

```
kSession.startProcess("sample.process.", oMap);
```

It will throws Null Pointer Exception for other Decision table which is not part of **sample.process**.

Second thing when we haven't execute kSession.fireAllRules(), then also will try execute to decision table(this decision table is not a part of current flow).

Comment: and the question is...?

Comment: Why it is calling other decision table which is not a part of current execution flow?

Comment: How are you "calling" it?